# Getting each instance of matched string from MatchData

Tags: ruby, regex

I am using a scan function with a regex that returns the following objects. The result of the scan is assigned to a h.

When I call h[0] however I only receive one instance of somedata1 even if occurs more than once. How can I filter the results so that I can count each instance of a matched string?

```
#<MatchData "somedata1">, #<MatchData "somedata1">, #<MatchData "somedata2">
```

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ EDIT +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

```
"sometext".to_enum(:scan, /someregex/).map { Regexp.last_match }
```

Comment: `String#scan` returns an array of strings, why do you have an array of `MatchData` instances?

Comment: I added the code I'm using above. I would to be able to save every instance that is matched to the regex, not just the first instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that simply looping/displaying through each instance of `#<MatchData "">` did the trick

Answer (score 0):

You can count the result with `count`.

`h` is an array so you can do

```
h.count
```

Comment: No, counting would have to come after the matching string are obtained. I still have no way to capture all of the matching instances.

Answer (score 0):

You should count it when you scanning
or use group_by

```
 r = a.group_by{|s| s.data}
 r.each{|k,v| p k + "=" + v.count.to_s}
```